# Problem - Upload spec on jenkinsfile.groovy script in artifactory

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm having some issues about uploading a spec in artifactory. When i build, I have this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 91; received: 0

I tried to solve this problems doing what similar questions' answers here told to do, but it didn't work.

the part of the code is:

def server = Artifactory.newServer url: "${UrlRepoAppDes}", credentialsId: "${ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS}"
                            println(ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS)

def uploadSpec = "{\"files\": [{\"pattern\": \"*.rpm\", \"target\": \"${repositoryName}/${artifactId}/\"}]}"

println(uploadSpec)

server.upload(uploadSpec)